# How to work with nested lists in iScroll / protect outer scrolling on inner scroll action?

Tags: javascript, iscroll

I want to hav a scrollable container that hosts a scrollable list with iScroll4. I got everything running on my own:

http://jsfiddle.net/BH2F3/

(does not work in the preview, so please download and try locally)

The PROBLEM now is:

When I do a scroll action on the list, also the outer container scrolls. How to I protect the outer container from scrolling and only apply the scroll action to the nested list? I already tried "snapping" to the list with no success. Do I have to bind to the "onBeforeScrollStart" ?

The official Implementation is : `onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }`, so I'd expect the outer container not to scroll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out:

It is not a matter of Default prevention but event bubbling.

The solution is in overwriting onBeforeScrollStart !

```
            onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            },
```

Answer (score 3):

For current version, the event `beforeScrollStart` don't have argument `event`. This can be done this way:

```
iscroll.on('beforeScrollStart', function() {
    scroll.disable();
});
iscroll.on('scrollEnd', function() {
    scroll.enable();
})
```